# Material turns white when using the option setDisplayEdges(true)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I recently discovered a strange behaviour using the autodesk forge viewer.

While viewing a model, i executed following code to add a red cube into my scene:

```
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
const geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,50,50);
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
NOP_VIEWER.impl.createOverlayScene('testOverlay', mat, mat);
NOP_VIEWER.impl.addOverlay('testOverlay', cube);
```

Regularly, the result would look as intended like this:

[Adding a colored cube as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcUCx.png)

However, in the application I'm working in, the option `setDisplayEdges` is set to `true` as standard.
This seems to have the effect that any custom material used within the viewer is displayed as white, as seen in this example:

[The same cube turned white without any change to the code itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L00gM.png)

I was able to reproduce this in multiple models.

Comment: tks for letting us know this and I am working with Engineering on fix and to come up with a workaround in the meantime - will let you know soon

Comment: thanks a lot - i disabled the option for now in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to report that this has been fixed with the latest [version 7.18](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/)